# join pandas dataframe with SQL output

Tags: sql, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe containing among other columns, a list of contracts `df['contract']`.
I have a SQL query that gives me first name and last name of the contract holder. I need to combine the query and the list of contracts.

`select firstname, lastname from holder where holder_contract= df['contract']`

How can I create a dataframe from `df` adding 2 columns firstname and lastname from my query?

---

**EDIT**: Tracks I explored

I extracted  one DF for one contract and could join it. 
I created a loop but the join match only one line, therefore the final dataframe has 1 line filled and the others are blank. If I want to use the merge, I need to create a big table containing all the values.

`zip( *map(lambda x: pd.read_sql_query(SQL.format(x),connection).loc[0], df.contract))` gives me the 2 columns I want but fails if there is no match.

Comment: Simply, read in query with [read_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) and merge with df. Include the join key `holder_contract` in query.

Comment: `df = read_sql("select firstname, lastname from holder where holder_contract= 0123456", engine=...)`

Comment: are you saying that I have to read first my table to extract the dataframe and then join with each of the 1 line dataframe ?

Comment: Are you using SQLAlchemy or writing plain queries?

Comment: Pain queries. The query argument is the contact number. I have to iterate on the contract column to retrieve all my information

Answer (score 0):

For an ordinary query, perhaps this will work:

```
qry = ("SELECT firstname, lastname "
       "FROM holder "
       "WHERE holder_contract IN {0};".format(tuple(df.contract)))
df = pd.read_sql(qry, engine=...)
```

Comment: This is not working because I cannot execute a IN statement. I have too many values.